# Does the universal "step-by-step" property of knowledge eg in The Meno conflict with the fluctuation theorem from statistical mechanics

Tags: epistemology, knowledge, physics

Background: There seems to be a universal property of knowledge, which is captured under Plato's reminiscence theory (remembrance), that acquiring knowledge necessary involves a series of steps that has to occur in some order. I claim this is an accurate reading from this previous question of mine (from [To obtain knowledge must we acquire specific other knowledge first?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92046/to-obtain-knowledge-must-we-acquire-specific-other-knowledge-first)).

> *yes* "it is a general principle for all knowledge" (Conifold) that "there are perhaps specific prerequisite knowledge...for certain other knowledge" (me)

I don't see how this universal aspect of knowledge comports with [the fluctuation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation_theorem) which says any physically possible event has some positive probability to occur regardless of the proceeding states of the universe, "there should always be some nonzero probability that the entropy of an isolated system might spontaneously decrease; the fluctuation theorem precisely quantifies this probability." To me, with some casual understanding of physics, this is liking saying it is physically possible for a purple dinosaur to appear in front of me at any time (exponentially unlikely of course).

I hope you see the conflict I am trying to track. It would seem physically, the world can pass through any order of points/states (with differing probabilities of course). Yet, knowledge is much more restricted according to the first paragraph. To reach certain points epistemically, other points may/do have to be reached first.

Whether knowledge is remembrance or not, it has some type of specific sequential nature to it, yet knowledge of the physical in light of the fluctuation theorem is not. There is no order to a purple dinosaur appearing suddenly. It's not a specific step that had to occur next to count as knowledge, and there was no specific epistemic step in between now and it appearing. So we can seemingly bypass this universal property of knowledge by learning about/observing any fluctuation in the physical. There's no prerequisite to it happening. As for a specific case of the "sequential" nature to knowledge, I'll just borrow Conifold's citing of The Meno and things like the learning process of how to double a square. I'm trying to demonstrate the dinosaur and the Meno examples argue entirely different things about knowledge, and saying is this really the case/how do we reconcile?

(Why I went with the fluctuation theorem and not quantum randomness for the breakdown of the "prerequisite" in the physical, I'm not sure, maybe the FT is more stark)

Comment: I don't see what problem you are talking. This question could use considerable more explanation.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I made some edits hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

No, they do not conflict. Classical physical systems evolve entirely deterministically, you'd say sequentially (in QM they do too, but that might breach the scope here).  Only one sequential time evolution is possible for a given well defined physical system.

Entropy is only a property of ill-defined or *unknown* physical systems. It's calculated based on mutual information/knowledge,or a pre-defined set of macroscopic variables (in thermodynamics).  The underlying state of a system has 0 entropy and remains at zero entropy forever, evolving in exactly one way.  Entropy can only be assigned when we say, "it could be in this state, or this state or this state... But I don't have enough info to know which"

So an entropy decrease via the fluctuation theorem or a Poincare Recursion doesn't violate deterministic evolution, it's a consequence of ignorance - using a probability distribution of possible micro-states a system might be in.  When the purple dinosaur appears, it was always going to happen - you just didn't know it.  It seems unlikely, but that's your fault, not because "there is no order..."

Comment: The only problem I have with this good answer is that QM is not deterministic about which specific outcomes occur, unless you are a many worlds or superdeterminist, or bohmian. So I can't just rest on determinism.

Comment: @JKusin Fair enough, although entropy is still out of the equation. And it's a pretty big "unless" nowadays...  Copenhagen is only referenced by people when they don't have to worry about the classical-quantum boundary. When the line is important, decoherence takes care of things in practice, meaning physicists never, in practice, have to invoke collapse.  "Unitary evolution only" would be the most common interpretation if it wasn't usurped by "many worlds" which sounds too mystical (and stupid) for folks to admit belief in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are reading too much into both the 'step by step' acquisition of knowledge and the FT. Yes, humans acquire knowledge gradually, and what we learn earlier helps us to understand what we encounter later, but there isn't a single path that everyone follows. Physically what seems to happen as we learn is that the brain 'rewires' itself. If what you are asking is whether the FT suggests the rewiring can be bypassed in some way, then there are at least three reasons why I would not be inclined to take the suggestion seriously.

The first is that the FT does not imply that a purple dinosaur can pop-up out of nowhere. The FT refers to configuration states in statistical mechanics, where the raw material consists of energetic particles in largely random motion. While random motion means a lot of outcomes are possible, it does not mean that any outcome is possible. The only outcomes with non-zero possibilities are those that are baked in to the ensemble at the outset. You can roll a trillion dice as many times as you like, but they can only show numbers from one to six, the total can't be less than zero or more than six trillion, and it can't be a fraction, an imaginary number, a word, etc etc.

Secondly, there is a lot of random thermal noise in brains, and yet our behaviour is anything but random. Presumably, therefore, brains have evolved with filters that ensure persistent patterns of thought regardless of random statistical fluctuations associated with heat.

Thirdly, where you have an ensemble of trillions of particles moving at random, the probability of an exceptional macrostate is so vanishingly close to zero that even if they could, theoretically, coalesce to form a dinosaur, you would have to wait trillions of times the life of the Universe before it happened. So I don't hold out much hope for ever becoming an accomplished violinist as a consequence of the FT causing my brain to rewire at random.

Comment: I fully aware the FT or QM don’t make “anything” possible. A purple dino is physically possible however, even if it never happens in a trillion years. smaller things are exponentially more likely to fluctuate into existence according to the FT so it’s not like we can rule out all small fluctuations from happening.

Comment: I can’t learn how to double a square without some math, but apparently my brain could fluctuate into an answer without acquiring said math (even though it’s so unlikely we can almost ignore it). Nevertheless, isn’t philosophy still interested in these types of differences?

Comment: @JKusin I often wonder how my mind finds the answers to the cryptic crossword. They sometimes seem to just pop into my head, so perhaps it is the good old FT coming to the rescue!

Comment: More seriously, if you wanted to make the case for the brain gaining knowledge through random thermal fluctuations you would have to do a lot more work to get me to take it seriously. Why do you say a purple dino is possible? How do you envisage it coming about? Fluctuations happen all the time, so they are not ruled out, but they are certainly averaged out.

Comment: Well, I'd like to ask you then why is the brain observing/learning of any fluctuation, no matter how tiny, not the brain gaining knowledge through random thermal fluctuations? The dino is fungible with any other psychical system. Consider an observable of a single particle tied to some thermodynamic/stat mech system. The thermodynamics have a chance to spontaneously change/reverse not aligned with the second law, ergo the particle/observable changes spontaneously too. That spontaneity is the language of one of the 3 pillars of modern physics (stat mech).

Comment: (also hopefully I don't feature in your next parody)

Answer (score 1):

This question implicitly assumes that knowledge involves certainty -- IE justified true belief, JTB.  But you apply this to empirical knowledge, knowledge of this world.  We cannot know "truth" about our world, so from JTB, T cannot be satisfied by empirical knowledge. It also cannot be justified with certainty, as we can never complete an infinite regress needed for complete justification, so we can't satisfy J either.

Empirical knowledge is not certain, but only probabilistic or useful.  It is sometimes wrong, and could fail to predict a purple dinosaur spontaneously manifesting.

We use sequential processes to make predictions based on past empirical knowledge, and these predictions are also knowledge.  Those predictions are sometimes wrong, as we observe surprises, and those observations are also knowledge.  We then use the surprises to modify our models, and make further predictions, which are also knowledge.  But none of this knowledge is certain.

Comment: Okay, well we can detect the dino scientifically upon fluctuating. that's not knowledge?

Comment: Sure its knowledge.  But our detectors could be in error, or our interpretation of the detectors, etc.  No knowledge is certain.

Comment: Okay now I'm confused :(. If it is knowledge, didn't we acquire it in a "random" way, by the dino/particle/etc being spontaneously generated according to the FT plus our observing of it? I'm taking the language of the FT to be unreducible to another theory, spontaneity included. If we can acquire knowledge this way, are you disagreeing knowledge must have some kind of "prerequisite"/"step-by-step" nature to it? (the part that made Plato think knowledge is remembering/in the linked question)

Comment: @JKusin -- In epistemology, I am a big advocate of using empiricism, with its indirect realism and intrinsic uncertainties, as our primary source of knowledge.  However, no indirect realism can operate without either knowledge based on reasoning, or with first person access to aspects of our universe.  Empirical methodology must admit to three different paths of knowledge acquisition.  I also argue, unlike most foundationalists, that both first person and rational knowledge are also uncertain.

Comment: Okay sounds like you would say the empirical FT (and empiricism in general) does kind of disagree with the epistemology in my linked question (which is mostly about knowledge proceeding in a series of somewhat specific steps, not certainty). And that both are a fork of knowledge?

Comment: @JKusin -- for the purple dinosaur, you seem to be assuming direct realism -- that we can know with certainty it exists, because we perceive it. But our perception is not certain -- we are mistaken a lot in what we perceive.  And yes, we have methodologies that help improve the accuracy of our knowledge -- reasoning checks, data quality checks, etc.  These are useful to get us more reliable knowledge, but still uncertain. All of reasoning checks, sensing checks, and empirical theory checks are useful, but the appropriate "sequences" are usually customized, so I don't follow the sequence focus.

Comment: It’s not certainty, it’s that in non-FT-“produced” knowledge like in the Meno, knowledge unlocks or leads to other relevant knowledge. The extra certainty of such a sequence is not a care of mine. It’s rather I can’t identify any inquiry (sequence) into a specific fluctuating occurrence—-the entropy just spontaneously decreased. There is no inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

> acquiring knowledge necessary involves a series of steps that has to occur in some order

I believe the same concept is known in psychology as Vygotsky's Zone of Proximal Development.

Imagine you are piecing together a jigsaw puzzle (Greek *logos* is a derivative from proto-Hellenic *lego*, which means "to assemble"). You can only make progress by adding pieces adjacent to the completed part of the puzzle. If someone shares with you a piece too soon, from too far away, you wouldn't know where it fits. True as this piece might be,<sup>1</sup> to you it would remain nothing more than the other person's opinion (*doxa*). Only when (and if) you expanded your puzzle far enough and fit that piece in, it will become part of your knowledge (*episteme*) -- in other words, it will become *your* truth as well.

This puzzle analogy also helps highlight the difference between learning and understanding -- and why Heraclitus wrote that no amount of the former would teach us to do the latter. Learning is the process of acquiring puzzle pieces. Understanding happens when we manage to fit them together and see the big picture that they represent. That's why simply collecting pieces, no matter how many and for how long, does not automatically translate to knowledge and understanding.

<sup>1</sup> Meaning the piece actually belongs to the puzzle. And, by the way, since we all live in (and aim to understand) the same Reality, we are also trying to complete the same puzzle, helping each other by sharing our pieces --  by sharing our knowledge.

P.S. As for the random dinosaurs (or random enlightenment), others already covered that part of the story -- in short, don't hold your breath :)

Comment: actually you made me think of another related concept, this time in geography, which says geography/land can only change in a way that directly relates to its local area. Traversing land, we can't be fully surprised. I will try to find it. Thank you for the puzzle analogy and the psychology principle. But I think the random enlightenment is equally important and doesnt feel settled to me yet.